# Optimize php multi curl in large traffic 100 req/sec

Tags: php, curl-multi

I have around 100 res/sec and then every single request is forwarded to 10 different urls. I am using curl_multi_exec to post my json to the urls and then receive response from each of them and manipulate it according to my needs. The problem is that it takes too much time for me around 300-500ms . I need this process to be completed in less than 200 ms. My partners have very little latencies.

Below is my code :

```
<?php

$post_data = 'some json';
$urls = array(
    'url1',
    'url2',
    'url3',
    'url4',
    'url5',
    'url6',
    'url7',
    'url8',
    'url9',
    'url10',
);

$mh = curl_multi_init();
$curl_array = array();
$curl_error_main = array();
$ping_info = array();
$ping_response = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++)
{
    $curl_array[$i] = get_rtb_ping_curl_request($urls[$i],$post_data);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
}

$active = null;

do {

        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);


for ( $i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++)
{

    $curl_error = curl_error($curl_array[$i]);
    $ping_info[$i] = curl_getinfo($curl_array[$i]);
    if (!$curl_error)
    {
        $ping_response[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_array[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        $curl_error_main[$i] = $curl_error;
    }
}


for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++)
{
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);


echo 'error';echo "\n";
print_r($curl_error_main);echo "\n";
echo ' curl info ';echo "\n";
print_r($ping_info);echo "\n";
echo ' response' ;echo "\n";
print_r($ping_response);echo "\n";

function get_rtb_ping_curl_request($url,$post_data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    $request_headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 2000);
    return $ch;
}

?>
```

In my research i found that this might be due to CPU load so changed my do while to below code but it didnt help

```
do {
    $j++;
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(1);
    }

    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
```

I also looked into guzzle but it seems it will take same amount of time

and using fsocket also wont optimise the time.

Please suggest a way to optimize my code or any other alternative to php curl that might help

Comment: You should try switching to Node JS,its non blocking.

Comment: I understand i need to change my technology but the project is too big to move to node JS right now. Hence looking for PHP only currently

Comment: Why are you bothering yourself with low level curl details? Use proven, well maintained and tested Guzzle library instead.

Comment: what's the total size of request and response data?

Comment: apparently your code blocks in the 2nd for loop, php now supports multi-threading, even if you're using older version, you can do multithreading using 'pecl' pthread library, so just start doing that stuff and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I just changed 1 micro second to 100 and it worked for me. 1 micro second just wasn't enough to process the response

```
        $active = null;
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
                usleep(100);
        }

        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
```